# Unicode Character 'SPEAKER WITH THREE SOUND WAVES' (U+1F50A) in c source code

Tags: c, unicode

I want to print Unicode Character 'SPEAKER WITH THREE SOUND WAVES' (U+1F50A) Encodings "\uD83D\uDD0A" in  C source code but get this output:

```
error: \uDD0A is not a valid universal character
error: \uD83D is not a valid universal character
```

Comment: Tried the obvious `\U0001F50A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\u` notation (with four hexadecimal digits) is referring to UCS-2 encoding, i.e. you can encode only characters from the BMP (Basic multilingual plane, basically `U+00000` through `U+0FFFF`).

`U+1F50A` is *beyond* the BMP, and thus cannot be encoded in 16 bits. UTF-16 uses surrogate pairs for such characters beyond the BMP (values in the `0xD800` - `0xDFFF` range, which are not used in UCS-2), but they are explicitly forbidden in `\u` notation.

You need `\U` notation (with eight hexadecimal digits) for that.

Also note that the conversion from either `\u` or `\U` notation to whatever actually ends up in the string is locale-dependent, so what might work on one platform might not work on another... if you want to be *really* portable and *ensure* e.g. UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding in the string, you need to:

- do the encoding manually via hexadecimal `\x...` or octal `\...`;
- use third-party libraries with *proper* Unicode support ([ICU](http://icu-project.org)).

---

While we're at it (and because many people are unaware of this), the above points straight at why Microsoft's 16bit version of `wchar_t` is broken when you want Unicode: It stems from a time when there *was* only the BMP, and 16bit UCS-2 was plenty enough. Since it is no longer sufficient to encode all defined Unicode characters, you can *use* it to hold UTF-16 code values, but `wchar_t` -- and by extension, `std::wstring` as well as `L""` string literals -- isn't really **wide** as the name implies, but **multibyte** at best.

Good that C++ introduced explicit `char16_t` and `char32_t`, plus the locale-independent `u""`, `U""` and `u8""` string literals. Too bad MSVC doesn't yet support them AFAIK.

Comment: Does it show that I have to juggle this stuff nine-to-five? ;-)

Comment: Erm, C++11 is broken for adding char16_t??  Or is it just MSFT that gets it wrong?  L"\U0001F50A" works perfectly fine on MSVC++.